# How to select column based on row value in a different column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the below dataframe and I would like to select the column based on the value in the 'AGE' column and perform a math calculation based on the value in that column for that row.

[image]

For example, for row 0 the AGE value is 5, therefore I need to pick value from the column 'MONTH_5' which is 0.288 and multiply it by the SALARY for that row, which is 1174.88 and populate the result (1174.88 * 0.288) in a new column named 'Final_Value'. Similarly, for row 1, the AGE value is 6, therefore I need to pick value from column 'MONTH_6' for that row (which is 0.025) and multiply it by the SALARY for that row, which is 3665.87 and populate the result (3665.87* 0.025) in a new column named 'Final_Value'. I need to do this for every row in the dataframe.

I tried to apply the logic using lambda, however, I'm unable to figure out how to select the column, based on the values in AGE column for each row in the dataframe.

```
def calculate_sal(age, salary):
    return_val = 0
    month_col_name = 'MONTH_' + str(age)
    return_val = my_df[month_col_name]
    return return_val * salary 

my_df['Final_Value'] = my_df.apply(lambda row: calculate_sal(row['AGE'],row['salary']), axis=1)
```

When I'm trying the above code, I'm getting the following error:

"ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 235, placement implies 1"

How can I achieve this? Please advise.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please copy/paste that sample data instead of an image?

Comment: Within your lambda you can fetch it using `row['MONTH_' + str(row['age'])]`. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

```
def calculate_sal(df, age):

    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if row["AGE"] == age:
            row["Final_Value"] = row["AGE"] * row["MONTH_" + str(age)]
        else:
            pass            
    return
```

Comment: Your `if` and `elif` conditions are the same. And so are the bodies of both blocks. Why do you have both of them?

Comment: And `elif:` should be `else:`

Comment: Kindly add enough details to your code so that the future readers can understand it.

Comment: There's no need for `else: pass`. Just leave out the `else:` clause completely.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can also try `np.arange` like [`Indexing and selecting data`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#looking-up-values-by-index-column-labels)

```py
idx, cols = pd.factorize('MONTH_'+df['AGE'].astype(str))
df['col'] = df.reindex(cols, axis=1).to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df)), idx]
```